# I am unable to enter 6E029 in a cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, cell-format

I am unable to enter the text from 6E000 to 6E999 in Excel.
Every time I enter this it is taking exponential form.
How can I format this to actual text?

Comment: Select the cell an format the cell as text ***BEFORE*** putting the value in the cell. You can format that whole column or row at once.  It is on the Home tab.

Comment: Alternatively - add single quote char in front of the value - i.e. insert `'6E029`.